How to fix/configure Python syntax highlighting?
Python syntax highlighting has recently stopped working correctly, even without any extensions enabled.
Is there a way to configure this? I cannot find any good resources on this, other than extensions providing custom syntax highlighting. This is something that is shipped with VSCode out of the box, so I would assume that it can be configured somehow?
A few things I checked:

I'm on the latest VSCode version (8/14)
No Python extensions are installed (no pylance etc.).
Changing color theme does not do anything. I don't even have custom themes.

Here is one example: It thinks that UPDATE (inside a comment) is the start of a new syntax node, and the entire highlighting in the file from there is entirely wrong:


What is the file type selected in bottom right ribbon (it starts with Ln X, Col Y) in VSC?

I made sure to select python. I updated the description.


No Python extensions are installed (no pylance etc.).

Syntax highlighting is provided by language server Pylance which is included in python extension instead of VSCode itself.
You need to install python extension to gain intellisense and syntax highlighting.
Add the settings "python.languageServer": "pylance" or "python.languageServer": "default" to your settings.json after installing the extension.
Read document for more details.
